# Get class from string and Pass parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method in objective-c which takes string and converting to class and passing some common object to it.

```
-(UIViewController*)getUIViewController{
 NSString* templateID = @"templateId"; // This value is coming from ba ckend
Class c = NSClassFromString(templateID);
UIViewController* vc = [[c alloc] initWithAppRender:appRenderer];
return vc;
}
```

Now the same thing converting to swift.

```
func getUIViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    let templateID = "templateId"
    let className = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String + "." + templateID
    let aClass = NSClassFromString(className) as! UIViewController.Type
    return aClass.init()
}
```

Here the problem is not able to pass common object which exists in all view controllers. I want to pass apprenderer object like in objective-c.

Comment: do you have a base controller for all your ViewController?

Comment: You would need to extend `UIViewController` to have an additional convenience `init` that accepts an `appRenderer`

Comment: @Kamran I don't have a base controller

Comment: @Paulw11 Even though i have convenience init. I need to warp the view controller from class object. I want to pass with out wrapping

Comment: Instantiating a class from `Type` can be done with `required` initializer but as we can not add a `required` initializer in `extension` so seems impossible by extending `UIViewController`. Can you share obj-c code of `initWithAppRender ` where it is defined, It might be helpful to find some solution?

Comment: I don't think that you can do this directly in Swift; probably because it is a crash fest waiting to happen. You would need to use the required initialiser `init(coder:)` and then somehow provide the app renderer object, which probably means that you are going to have to subclass UIViewController since extensions can't add properties.

Comment: initWithAppRender is defined in all of my view controller .h files

Comment: @Paulw11 Class can not instantiate from its metaType without required initializer and required init can not be declared in an extension

Comment: Yes, that is why I updated my comment.  Short answer you need to have all of your view controllers inherit from a common subclass of `UIViewController` so that you can add the `appRenderer` property and set it.  Swift does far more compile-time checking than Objective-C so you can't just tell the compiler to dispatch methods at runtime and have the compiler trust you that they will be there.  Swift wants to *know* that they will be there.

Comment: Even If i use required init, I can't pass my apprender with out knowing the class type right ?

Comment: Right - that is why you need to use a common subclass of `UIViewController`.  Then you don't need to know the specific class of the final view controller; you just know that it will inherit from your `AppRenderViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a base class for all your ViewControllers like this,

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    private var render: NSObject?

    required init(appRenderer: NSObject?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.render = appRenderer
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And then you can instantiate from the server returned class name as below,

```
func getUIViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    let templateID = "templateId"
    let className = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String + "." + templateID
    let aClass = NSClassFromString(className) as! BaseViewController.Type
    let vc = aClass.init(appRenderer: nil)
    return vc
}
```

Comment: can u please suggest how to load view from storyboard in this case.